# Docker compose failed to build: COPY failed:, can't find package.json in the root directory

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, package.json

First time using docker. please help!

I got this. how can i fix it?

```
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
ERROR: Service 'buyer' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

I have my code file under one folder running. I put them in different folder to create docker. My file structure is like below

```
├── buyer
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── client.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── iotaModule.js
├── seller
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.js
│   └── iotaModule.js
├── docker-compose.yml
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── .dockerignore
```

my dockerfile for seller

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /seller

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

my dockerfile for buyer

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /buyer

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "client.js" ]
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  seller:
    container_name: docker_seller
    build: seller/
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - buyer
  buyer:
    container_name: docker_buyer
    build: buyer/
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `COPY ../package*.json ./` since you your Dockerfile is located in a subfolder?

Comment: @scorpioo590 yes, dockerfile is in a subfolder and package.json in root folder. So ../ would access it back to root golfer right?

Comment: @matt offtopic: first `COPY` and then `npm install` because some modules are built for specific OS

Answer (score 0):

`COPY ../package*.json ./` didnt work somehow. I put package,json inside the subfolder and that works. probably not the best way to do it.